# Dynamo DB Health Check in JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, health-check

I have been trying to do a health check of AWS DynamoDB using Lambda fn in java using the dynamodb: ListTables Action.
However, due to restrictions on the existing role, I am getting AccessDeniedException.
I even tried to list out a specific table name like this:

```
ListTablesRequest request = new ListTablesRequest().withLimit(10).withExclusiveStartTableName("<existing table name>");
```

This returned

```
INFO: List tables request {ExclusiveStartTableName:<existing table name> ,Limit: 10}
```

It would also be helpful if I get to specify a startsWith pattern with reference to the List Tables parameter.
But apart from ListTables is there any other way of doing a health check on DDB?

Comment: What do you mean by `a health check of AWS DynamoDB`?

Comment: It means we need to check if a healthy connection is being established with the DDB service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "health check" you mean check that you have a working correction with the given DynamoDB endpoint, the fastest and easiest way is to send an HTTP or HTTPS request to "/" on the endpoint. The response is a simple "healthy" message:

```
$ curl https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
healthy: dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

For better and for worse, this sort of health check doesn't require any authentication or authorization (roles). It's better because it's faster, simpler, and because you said you had a problem with your authorization. But for the same reason, it's worse because it doesn't check your authorization, so it is possible that your health check will succeed but the actual request will not - because you don't have the right permissions.

Comment: How should I handle this via code? Is a GET call on this url(https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/) rendering 200 OK sufficient to conclude that connection with DynamoDB is healthy?

Comment: Yes, a GET request (instead of the usual POST request one sends to DynamoDB). ‎This specific URL is for the us-west-2 (Oregon) geographic region, replace it by the actual geographic endpoint you are using for your actual DynamoDB requests. Also, better to check, beyond the 200 OK, that the body starts with the word "healthy:". Otherwise, even "http://www.google.com" would appear to be a healthy DynamoDB endpoint, just because it responds to the HTTP request :-)